# Android 11 - Scoped storage - unable to use java.io.File even after Uri permissions are granted

Tags: android, android-11, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I'm currently migrating an Android app to [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). Moving away from `java.io.file` is a *real* nightmare, and feels much of a drawback to me. I'm currently trying to understand if paths returned by [`getExternalMediaDirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()) can effectively be used with [direct file paths](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths).

After asking user to select a given folder

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and storing persistent `Uri` permissions to read/write in `onActivityResult`

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(), (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION));
```

Is it **expected to still not being able to use `java.io.File` in such granted path**?

SAF path:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid/media/com.otherapp/test.txt
```

equivalent to `java.io.File` path

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.otherapp/test.txt
```

Some final notes:

- such path **can** be written with SAF
- such path **cannot** be written with direct `java.io.File` path (`EACCES` exception)
- `/Android/media/com.otherapp` is different than self-attributed `/Android/media/com.app`
- `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` not available

thanks
nicola

Comment: Indeed you cannot use the File class for such content scheme uries. But why would you? Use the uri directly.

Comment: The equivalence stands. You used something like getRealPathForUri(). Even if you managed to find the file system path you have no access on an Android 11+ device as that file does not belong to your app. Otherwise you could access it.

Comment: thanks @blackapps. Just for context: the reason behind using `java.io.File` is that we have complex path traversal logics, whose transposition to `Uri` would open a whole pletora of side issues. Given your answer, I believe we will not have other choices other than accept this and use SAF to access the path.

Comment: @blackapps sorry if I misuse this thread and your expertise, but would this be the same matter for files in `Download` folder, meaning for the same logic we cannot access `java.io.File` in such folder even if `Uri` permission is granted? We're handling huge ZIP files and without `java.io.File` access it would mean `zip4j` wouldn't be able to handle these without copying it somewhere else (madness...) ref. https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j/issues/273#issuecomment-766085307

Comment: If you have an uri permission you have permission to use that uri. This does not mean that if you manage to find its file system path that you have permission for that path. If you can download a file to public Download directory then you have access to that file. Both by using file system path or for example uri obtained from downloadmanager.

Comment: If zip4j can read from an inputstream you can simply use the uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because after granting permissions you have access to `Content Scheme Uri` of that specific folder not file system paths so you will be unable to list java.io.File objects using this Uri.

But you can use it to `listFiles()` which will return you a list of [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile). You can then use these `DocumentFile` objects to get `Uri` of that specific file using [documentFile.getUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getUri()) . Using that `Uri` you can easily perform basic operations like `display,copy,delete,share` on that file.

**Below is an example of listing files from a folder of other app.**

*I am skiping take permissions part of code assuming that you already have permissions to access that other app's folder*

**In this example i am listing files from Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses**

DOC Ids are

```
companion object {
    const val ANDROID_DOCID = "primary:Android/media/"
    const val EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.android.externalstorage.documents"
    private val androidUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(
        EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID
    )
    val androidTreeUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
        EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, ANDROID_DOCID
    )
}
```

**After getting permission we have tree Uri**

Here tree Uri is `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:Android/media`

```
val dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(
    context,
   treeUri!!
)
```

This dir is a DocumentFile, now using this to list all folders inside that tree Uri.

```
val selectedPackageName = “com.whatsapp”
val FOLDER_NAME_STATUSES = ".Statuses”;
val selectedRootName = “WhatsApp"
var waStatus: DocumentFile? = null
val statusesFiles = arrayListOf<DocumentFile>()
dir?.listFiles()?.forEach {
    if (it.name.equals(selectedPackageName)) {
        it.listFiles().forEach {
            if (it.name.equals(selectedRootName)) {
                it.listFiles().forEach {
                     if (it.name.equals(Constants.FOLDER_NAME_STATUSES)) {
                                waStatus = it
                         statusesFiles.addAll(waStatus!!.listFiles().filter {
                                    it.mimeType.equals(Constants.MIME_TYPE_IMG_PNG) || it.mimeType.equals(
                                        Constants.MIME_TYPE_IMG_JPG
                                    ) || it.mimeType.equals(Constants.MIME_TYPE_IMG_JPEG)
                                }.sortedByDescending { it.lastModified() })

                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now we have a list of `DocumentFile` from folder of another app. Use `Uri` of this file for further operations like `display,copy,delete,share`.

**Also, read comments** your point about `Downloads` folder `but would this be the same matter for files in Download`

Downloads is a public directory, i listed files which are created by my own app using listFiles() and it returned me list of [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File).

```
 val folder = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        Constants.DOWNLOADS_APP_DIRECTORY_NAME
    )
      if (folder != null && folder.exists()) {
                val newFiles: Array<File> = statusFolderInDownloads.listFiles({ file ->
                    getFileType(file.path) == FILETYPE.IMAGE || getFileType(file.path) == FILETYPE.VIDEO
                })
                list.addAll(newFiles)
                list.sortByDescending { it.lastModified() }
                if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                    return list
                } else {
                    return arrayListOf()
                }
            }
```

Comment: One thing to note, since it's driving me crazy: these 2 things are NOT equivalent to traverse the paths: `grantedUri.findFile(FOLDER)` is granted as well, while it's not with `DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(path+FOLDER)`

Comment: @NicolaBeghin findFile returns you DocumentFile whereas buildTreeDocumentUri will return you the uri of that Document File.

Comment: @NicolaBeghin i would also suggest you to checkout this Github library this might help you for performing operations like DocumentFile.search(), DocumentFile.copyFileTo() and much more https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage